# Delay after the splash screen

Tags: android, dialog, delay, splash-screen

My problem is, if I set my splash as a `Dialog` by adding this line in the manifest there's a delay: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar"`

After the splash screen disappears it takes around 6 seconds or more to the main activity to appear.

How can I make this delay disappear?

Splash code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
private final int DURATION = 3000;
private Thread mSplashThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    mSplashThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(DURATION);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                } finally {
                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }

    };
mSplashThread.start();
```

}

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        synchronized (mSplashThread) {
            mSplashThread.notify();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using a delayed `Handler`?

Comment: No, if I just remove that line from the Manifest there's no delay anywhere. It's only when I add that line to see my splash as a dialog.

Comment: post your Splash screen code

Comment: I've added it editing the main message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using splash as dialogue you can do all your background work in a splash screen activity and then start  your main activity..if you need dialogue animation then you can use animation like this.

overridePendingTransition( R.anim.come_up, R.anim.go_down );

By this you can manage your activity switching time.

Comment: I need my splash screen to look like a dialog (small window in the middle of the mobile screen).

Comment: I think you are not using your splash for downloading data..If so then why don't you start main activity and in onCreate() make a splash dialogue and that time override onBackpress() so that your dialogue can be dismissed at disposal.

Comment: Sorry, do you have some example of that? I'm just starting with android

Comment: In your new edit code call finish(); after                  startActivity(intent); .I think this may also solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me at its best..

```
final int splashTimeOut = 3000;

    Thread splashThread = new Thread(){
                int wait = 0;
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        super.run();
                        while(wait < splashTimeOut){
                            sleep(100);
                            wait += 100;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }finally{
    startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            splashThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code for splashscreen display with some time delay
..
       here set splash image in drawable in splash_screen.xml.

```
 import android.location.Criteria;
 import android.location.Location;
 import android.location.LocationListener;
 import android.location.LocationManager;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity  {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider, formattedDate, imeid;
double lat, lon;



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());



    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i("JO", "run");
            Intent in = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,SecondActivity.class);
            //in.putExtra("refreshclick", clickRefreshButton);
            //in.putExtra("Current_Date", formattedDate);
        //  in.putExtra("ImeiId", imeid);
//Log.i("JO", "Current_Date"+formattedDate+";
     ImeiId"+imeid+";lat"+lat+"lon"+lon);
            startActivity(in);

            finish();
        }
    }, 1000);

}



    }
```

Comment: So, this would set a delay after my splash right? The issue is that I have a delay and I don't want any delay after the splash,

Comment: the above is not delay after splash screen shown, its for just showing splashscreen that above specified time..

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }
        }, DURATION);
    }
```